# How to delete a column after calling stack on pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, stack, multi-index

Currently, I have this:

[image]

and I used `.stack().rename_axis(['Gender', 'Cancer', 'Stage', 'Age group'])` to get this:

[image]

But I want to remove the last column (with the values 90.907707 ...) to have a table with only the mutliindex. Something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do so:

First, you can use `reset_index()` and then remove the last column (which would have the default name of `0`):

```
df2.reset_index().drop([0], axis=1)
```

Another way to do so is to get the `.index` attribute and convert it to DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
```